# Drupal Webform HTML Email fine on Dev box, Text when deployed to server

Tags: html-email, drupal-webform

Using Drupal 9.2.7 and Webform 6.1.2, I got the webform and html email working well on my dev machine.  I am running WSL2 on Windows, and using Mailhog to validate the emails without an SMTP server.  All looked good.

I copied the project to my test domain on A2Hosting and the emails come through as plain text.

I then installed Mail System and Mime Mail thinking that might be the problem.  Mail hog shows nice emails in either the html or text version, but when sent from A2Hosting I see the text version and raw html in the same email. My email client (eM Client) say the email is in  html format.

Unfortunately I do not have another place I can test this.  Could Mailhog be hiding a configuration problem on my part or is there a chance A2Hostings mail system is mucking it up?

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be quite simple.  I removed Mime Mail and Mail System, installed SMTP module, pointed it at an email account in my domain, and everything worked just as expected.